# linux - create a syscall - has sysdep.h been replaced?

Tags: c, linux, debian, glibc

I am trying to create a dummy system call in the linux kernel. It is my first time on stackoverflow, so please, bear with me.

I use debian testing.

I read [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Implement-Sys-Call-Linux-2.6-i386/) how to do. But when I

```
#include <sysdep.h>
```

in my usermode application, it seems that gcc cannot find it :

```
fatal error: sysdep.h: No such file or directory
```

libc6-dev is installed but no way.

I read [there](https://arvindsraj.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/adding-hello-world-system-call-to-linux/) that he is using

`#include <sys/syscall.h>`

Which I have. So what is the deal I have with sysdep.h ? Is it needed ?

Thank you

## Update

Ok, the debian source doesn't have it, they may have removed it.

So don't try to find it on Debian family, just use .

Cheers !

Comment: Are you compiling the user-mode program. Or the kernel?

Comment: hm I am compiling the user mode program, yes.

Comment: Hm. The sites you link to don't include "sysdep.h", my system doesn't have it either, and `man 2 syscall` doesn't mention it but mentions `<sys/syscall.h>`. Do you have any missing declarations without `<sysdep.h>`? If not, you probably don't need it.

Comment: After a search, I saw that the file eventfd.c also have it in the glibc source (sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/eventfd.c) . I already used eventfd (a few days ago), so why didn't it bothered at that compilation time ? It seems it found it ! My args are always the same : gcc -O3 -std=c11 bla.c -o bla

Comment: Ah.. i did my search in the original source. Debian remove it and it seems that sys/syscall is the way to go on this system family. :) Thanks !